# Extract the data between script tag using java regular expression

Tags: javascript, java, regex, jsoup

I want to extract the data given between the script tag. I also made a regex for this but it is not working on this string  -

```
<script>
var arrowimages = {
  down: ['downarrowclass', 'Images/arrow-down.gif', 23],
  right: ['rightarrowclass', 'Images/submenu-pointer.png']
}

var jqueryslidemenu = {

  animateduration: {
    over: 400,
    out: 400
  }, //duration of slide in/ out animation, in milliseconds

  buildmenu: function (menuid, arrowsvar) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var $mainmenu = $("#" + menuid + ">ul")
        var $headers = $mainmenu.find("ul").parent()
        $headers.each(function (i) {
            var $curobj = $(this)
            var $subul = $(this).find('ul:eq(0)')
            this._dimensions = {
              w: this.offsetWidth,
              h: this.offsetHeight,
              subulw: $subul.outerWidth(),
              subulh: $subul.outerHeight()
            }
            this.istopheader = $curobj.parents("ul").length == 1 ? true : false
            $subul.css({
              top: this.istopheader ? this._dimensions.h + "px" : 0
            })
            $curobj.children("a:eq(0)").css(this.istopheader ? {
              paddingRight: arrowsvar.down[2]
            } : {}).append(
              '<img src="' + (this.istopheader ? arrowsvar.down[1] : arrowsvar.right[1]) + '" class="' + (this.istopheader ? arrowsvar.down[0] : arrowsvar.right[0]) + '" style="border:0;top:12px;" />'
            )
            $curobj.hover(
                function (e) {
                  var $targetul = $(this).children("ul:eq(0)")
                  this._offsets = {
                    left: $(this).offset().left,
                    top: $(this).offset().top
                  }
                  var menuleft = this.istopheader ? 0 : this._dimensions.w
                  menuleft = (this._offsets.left + menuleft + this._dimensions.subulw > $(window).width()) ? (this.istopheader ? -this._dimensions.subulw + this._dimensions.w : -this._dimensions.w) : menuleft
                  if($targetul.queue().length <= 1) //if 1 or less queued animations
                    $targetul.css({
                    left: menuleft + "px",
                    width: this._dimensions.subulw + 'px'
                  }).slideDown(jqueryslidemenu.animateduration.over)
                },
                function (e) {
                  var $targetul = $(this).children("ul:eq(0)")
                  $targetul.slideUp(jqueryslidemenu.animateduration.out)
                }
              ) //end hover
            $curobj.click(function () {
              $(this).children("ul:eq(0)").hide()
            })
          }) //end $headers.each()
        $mainmenu.find("ul").css({
          display: 'none',
          visibility: 'visible'
        })
      }) //end document.ready
  }
}

//build menu with ID="myslidemenu" on page:
jqueryslidemenu.buildmenu("myjquerymenu", arrowimages)

</script>
```

My regex is- `<script[^>]*>(.*?)</script>`

other normal script tags like  `<script type="text/javascript" src="JsFiles/jquery.min.js"></script>` are retrieved by my regular expression but i don't know why it is not working on that particular string. I needed the data between text to modify that data so grouping is required too. i have also tried jsoup for doing this task -

```
    Elements scripts = doc.select("script");
 for(Element script: scripts) {
   System.out.println("src " + script);
   String lineread = script.toString();
   String data = script.data();
   if(!data.isEmpty()) {
     System.out.println(data);
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"|'([^']*)'");
     Matcher m = p.matcher(lineread);
     while(m.find()) {
       if(m.group(0).contains(".axd") || m.group(0).contains(".JPG") || m.group(0).contains(".jpg") || m.group(0).contains(".jpeg") || m.group(0).contains(".png") || m.group(0).contains(".js") || m.group(0).contains(".ico") || m.group(0).contains(".gif")) {
         System.out.println("m.g(0) " + m.group(0));
         System.out.println("m.g(1) " + m.group(1));
         String changepath;
         Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("src=(.*?)>|src=\"(.*?)\"");
         Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(m.group(0));
         if(m1.find()) {
           if(m1.group(0).contains(".axd") || m1.group(0).contains(".JPG") || m1.group(0).contains(".jpg") || m1.group(0).contains(".jpeg") || m1.group(0).contains(".png") || m1.group(0).contains(".js") || m1.group(0).contains(".ico") || m1.group(0).contains(".gif")) {
             System.out.println("inner " + m1.group(0));
             changepath = "\"" + main_url + "" + m1.group(1).replace("\"", "").replace("'", "") + "\"";

             lineread = lineread.replace(m1.group(1), changepath);
             System.out.println("data " + lineread);
           }
         } else {
           changepath = "\"" + main_url + "" + m.group(0).replace("\"", "").replace("'", "") + "\"";

           lineread = lineread.replace(m.group(0), changepath);
           System.out.println("data in src " + lineread);
         }
       }
     }
     script = script.text(lineread);
     System.out.println("final script " + script);

   }
 }
```

but the problem in this is the value i am getting in script(the last variable) remove all the spaces that are present in data between the script tag.

so basically i want either a regular expression for getting the data between script tag or how can i get the data without loosing spaces from second solution.

Comment: It may be helpful to give us what you expect the output to look like. Sometimes the requirements can get lost in translation. :-)

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: i am not getting any error .It is just not detecting that particular tag

Comment: i want output like this  -   var arrowimages = {
  down: ['downarrowclass', 'http://www.aed.tn.gov.in/Images/arrow-down.gif', 23],
  right: ['rightarrowclass', 'http://www.aed.tn.gov.in/Images/submenu-pointer.png']
}

var jqueryslidemenu = {

  animateduration: {
    over: 400,
    out: 400
  }, //duration of slide in/ out animation, in milliseconds

  ........................................and the complete scripting code after this

Comment: Don't forget to move `Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("src=(.*?)>|src=\"(.*?)\"");` out of your while loop. It is invariant inside of it.

Comment: sorry sir i am not getting what you are trying to say. i mean why out of the loop? can you explain more

Answer (score 0):

you can use the lib js2xml.
https://github.com/redapple/js2xml

```
import js2xml

jscode = """var arrowimages = {
  down: ['downarrowclass', 'Images/arrow-down.gif', 23],
  right: ['rightarrowclass', 'Images/submenu-pointer.png']
}

var jqueryslidemenu = {

  animateduration: {
    over: 400,
    out: 400
  }, //duration of slide in/ out animation, in milliseconds

  buildmenu: function (menuid, arrowsvar) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var $mainmenu = $("#" + menuid + ">ul")
        var $headers = $mainmenu.find("ul").parent()
        $headers.each(function (i) {
            var $curobj = $(this)
            var $subul = $(this).find('ul:eq(0)')
            this._dimensions = {
              w: this.offsetWidth,
              h: this.offsetHeight,
              subulw: $subul.outerWidth(),
              subulh: $subul.outerHeight()
            }
            this.istopheader = $curobj.parents("ul").length == 1 ? true : false
            $subul.css({
              top: this.istopheader ? this._dimensions.h + "px" : 0
            })
            $curobj.children("a:eq(0)").css(this.istopheader ? {
              paddingRight: arrowsvar.down[2]
            } : {}).append(
              '<img src="' + (this.istopheader ? arrowsvar.down[1] : arrowsvar.right[1]) + '" class="' + (this.istopheader ? arrowsvar.down[0] : arrowsvar.right[0]) + '" style="border:0;top:12px;" />'
            )
            $curobj.hover(
                function (e) {
                  var $targetul = $(this).children("ul:eq(0)")
                  this._offsets = {
                    left: $(this).offset().left,
                    top: $(this).offset().top
                  }
                  var menuleft = this.istopheader ? 0 : this._dimensions.w
                  menuleft = (this._offsets.left + menuleft + this._dimensions.subulw > $(window).width()) ? (this.istopheader ? -this._dimensions.subulw + this._dimensions.w : -this._dimensions.w) : menuleft
                  if($targetul.queue().length <= 1) //if 1 or less queued animations
                    $targetul.css({
                    left: menuleft + "px",
                    width: this._dimensions.subulw + 'px'
                  }).slideDown(jqueryslidemenu.animateduration.over)
                },
                function (e) {
                  var $targetul = $(this).children("ul:eq(0)")
                  $targetul.slideUp(jqueryslidemenu.animateduration.out)
                }
              ) //end hover
            $curobj.click(function () {
              $(this).children("ul:eq(0)").hide()
            })
          }) //end $headers.each()
        $mainmenu.find("ul").css({
          display: 'none',
          visibility: 'visible'
        })
      }) //end document.ready
  }
}

//build menu with ID="myslidemenu" on page:
jqueryslidemenu.buildmenu("myjquerymenu", arrowimages)"""

parsed = js2xml.parse(jscode)
print js2xml.pretty_print(parsed)
```

Example output:

```
<program>
  <var name="arrowimages">
    <object>
      <property name="down">
        <array>
          <string>downarrowclass</string>
          <string>Images/arrow-down.gif</string>
          <number value="23"/>
        </array>
      </property>
      <property name="right">
        <array>
          <string>rightarrowclass</string>
          <string>Images/submenu-pointer.png</string>
        </array>
      </property>
    </object>
  </var>
```

And then you can parse the XML. (is more easy with xpath)

Regards
Nelson.

Comment: Sir, your solution is right at your place but i can't change it like this. my concern is not just getting the images and change its path. i can't change my script in xml becuse it will not fullfill what i exactly want. See, i am downloading my webpage and for showing that image on my local host i need to give exact location of the image where it is originally stored. so i can't change the code like you give in the solution

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `data()` method, try the `html()` method.
The line `String data = script.data();` becomes `String data = script.html()`.

On the other hand, if you want to change the `src` attributes of script tags, you can simply tell Jsoup to find them for you:

```
Elements scripts = doc.select("script[src]");
for(Element script: scripts) {
    String src = script.attr("src");
    if (src.contains(".axd")) {
       script.attr("src", main_url + src);
    }
}
```

Comment: this will not work for detecting this pattern because it only works when src attribute present in the script tag